# DropDownListFor using ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Im trying to change the code in an existing project to make a DropDownListFor to select an item. I have read countless of threads but i do not get an specific item to get selected;

This is what i got;

Controller;

```
ViewData("MyDropDownList") = new SelectList(_myRepository.GetData, "data_id", "name"})
```

View;

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.data_id, TryCast(ViewData("MyDropDownList"), SelectList))
```

And this produces a nice list that looks something like this;

```
<select id="someId" name="someName" data-val="true">
<option value="aec385a7-bd77-4b94-9fbb-130487e3e62e">Option1</option>
<option value="5edee514-e6ca-456f-a8fa-71bde67351a1">Option2</option>
<option value="8a293328-8b11-47b7-bc9a-ceddf2e6a355">Option3</option>
</select>
```

After abit of reading i was pretty sure that this would work for making "Option2" selected;

```
ViewData("MyDropDownList") = new SelectList(_myRepository.GetData, "data_id", "name", "5edee514-e6ca-456f-a8fa-71bde67351a1"})
```

But it didn't, i have also tried this;

```
  ViewData("MyDropDownList") = new SelectList(_myRepository.GetData, "data_id", "name", New With {Key .id = "5edee514-e6ca-456f-a8fa-71bde67351a1"} })
```

What am i doing wrong? VB is not my cup of tea so it might as well just be a syntax screw up. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC if the view is strongly typed the selectlist’s selected option will be overridden and the selected option property set on the constructor will never reach the view and the first option in the dropdown will be selected instead (why is still a bit of a mystery). To overcome this issue all that needs to be done is to rename the DropDownList in the view and also the name of the ViewData’s key in the controller to something other than the name set in the model , and the selected option will then reach the view. Unfortunately when posting the form you will have to access the selected option’s value from the FormCollection rather than a strongly typed object which is a little annoying.

Source :http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2009/06/25/net-mvc-selectlists-selected-value-does-not-get-set-in-the-view/

Comment: Hi! And thanks for the reply. I tried to rename MyDropDownList to TADAAAA in both the View and controller without any luck. Am i doing it right?

Comment: please change your code to following new SelectList(_myRepository.GetData, "data_id", "name", new {data_id = 5edee514-e6ca-456f-a8fa-71bde67351a1});

Comment: Ah, seems logical, Do you now to write that in VB?